# How to set the "current" directory of a Dockerfile with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker

I have the following project structure:

```
.
..
project/
docker/cli/Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

In `docker-compose.yml` I have the following configuration:

```
cli:
  build: docker/cli
```

And somewhere in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY . /app
```

Now the problem is that when I do `docker-compose build cli` docker copies the contents of `docker/cli/` in `/app` in my image. Which makes sense because that is the relative path to my `docker/cli/Dockerfile`. Is there a way however to tell in my `docker-compose.yml` config that the path should be different (namely the root dir of my project where the actual project files are)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `context` attribute of a `build` instruction inside the docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  cli:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/cli/Dockerfile
```

This should work as desired. The `context` is what is sent to the docker daemon for build. You will also want a .dockerignore file in your `project` directory though, to ensure only what you need is sent.